# Automatically remove linebreaks while pasting on MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have to manually copy stuff from PDF to a Word Document but on each paragraph I have to Replace the line breaks using Replace function - `^p` 
Is there a way to automate it so that Word automatically does it each time something is pasted?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose "Paste Options - No Format Text" when pasting

[image]

But you need to retype the document.

According to my research, there is no other way to solve this situation.

Comment: I have tried that, but it keeps missing a lot of text. I wish it was possible to automate it with a script or something

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think this can be solved by code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to remove the line break when pasting a word(s) into a Word document.
When you copy the text, make sure you just copy the text, NO EXTRA SPACE AT THE END OF TEXT. When you paste (Ctrl+V) text should copy as it with no return.
Works for me, hope this helps?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).